# How to set jqueryui tooltip tip font size

Tags: jquery, tooltip, font-size

Sample tooltip at jqueryui.com/tooltip/ displays the tooltip itself ("That's what this widget is") on hover with a small font size.

[image: their tooltip]

I cannot duplicate that font size. When I try to match their sample, the tip displays with a larger font.

[image: my tooltip]

I downloaded and applied the style.css file used in their sample. The font size spec must be buried there; but I cannot find it.

(Maybe the solution lies in building a custom theme, though I am using their style.css file. That would seem to be way too complicated for what I want to do.)

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

this worked for me:

```
.ui-tooltip-content {
    font-size:10pt;
    font-family:Calibri;
}
```

Comment: FWIW (8 years later lol): when I downloaded jQuery Builder in 2022, the class was ".ui-tooltip", but changing the font attributes there works the same as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the following class:

```
 .ui-tooltip-content {
   font-size: 1em;
   font-family: Tahoma;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
.tooltip{
    font-size:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using bootstraps jQuery tooltip, the one with `data-toggle="tooltip"` and using the selector `.tooltip-inner` worked for me. Followed the bootstrap doc guidelines.